# Как работать с push уведомлениями laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, push-уведомления, google-cloud-messages

Добрый день. Мне необходимо реализовать отправку push увдеомлений, через gcm на мобильное устройсво. 
Использую эту библиотек https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification. Не понимаю как создать токен устройства и как проверить отправку pusha, если разрабатываю только сервер и не имею доступ к мобильному приложению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Токен должно получить мобильное приложение. После этого, приложение отправляет этот токен вам на сервер и вы сохраняете его за определённым юзером. Когда этому юзеру нужно отправить пуш, вытаскиваете его токен и отправляете на него сообщение.

Comment: Можно как-то получить токен через консоль разработчика?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нет.